# Установка цвета фона при наведении на элемент

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Не меняет цвет фона `$items` (при `hover`) в коде:

```
$(function() {
    var $items = $('.menu > li').not('.checked');
    $items.mouseover(function () {
        var cat_clr = $(this).css("borderColor");
        $(this).css("backgroundColor", cat_clr);
    });
    $items.mouseout(function () {
        $items.css("backgroundColor", "none");
    });
});
```

В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Отсутствие `background-color` задаётся с помощью значения `transparent`.
- В *Firefox* присутствует проблема с `borderColor`, поэтому вместо этого свойства можно использовать, например, `borderTopColor`.

Пример:

```js
$(function() {
    var $items = $('.menu > li').not('.checked');
    $items.mouseover(function() {
        var cat_clr = $(this).css("borderTopColor");
        $(this).css("backgroundColor", cat_clr);
    });
    $items.mouseout(function() {
        $items.css("backgroundColor", "transparent");
    });
});
```

```css
.menu li {
    border-color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромнейшее, очень помогло

Comment: В Мозиле не работает

Comment: @МишаУмаров переписал ответ.